# JDialog loses opacity after deiconify

Tags: java, swing

Creating a transparent and undercoated `JDialog` with a `JFrame` as its parent
will lose transparency upon an iconify/deiconify sequence.

Example:

```
final JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(200, 200);

final JDialog d = new JDialog(f, false);
d.setSize(200, 200);
d.setUndecorated(true);
d.setOpacity(.8f);

f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
d.setLocation(f.getLocation().x + 210, f.getLocation().y);

f.setVisible(true);
d.setVisible(true);
```

Before iconify, the JDialog is created fine.  Here is a screenshot.

[image]

After an iconify/deiconify sequence, the JDialog is 100% opaque.

[image]

I'm looking for solution to this problem and thinking I'm doing something 
incorrect or missing some code.

My environment is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12) 
running on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601].

***2014-11-13: There is an open JDK bug for this problem***

```
JDK-8062946 Transparent JDialog will lose transparency upon iconify/deiconify sequence.
```

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062946

Comment: This could be because the native resources are been disposed of between showings...you could try using a Window?isterner, but it might already be to late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  I've had various problems with the undecorated JDialog and when I find a 
bypass to a new symptom I add it to this method.  This is a trimmed example.  Add error checking, exception handling and modify as necessary to suit your needs ( ie add listener removal code if your app creates and destroys passed *parentWindow* objects).

```
package trimmed.stackoverflow.example;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Helper_Swing {

private static Helper_Swing instance;

private Helper_Swing() {
    instance = this;
}

public static Helper_Swing getInstance() {
    return instance == null ? new Helper_Swing() : instance;
}

private static class J42WindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

    final private Window  window;
    final private JDialog dialog;
    private Color         colorBG = null;
    private float         opacity = 0.0f;

    private J42WindowAdapter(final Window window, final JDialog dialog) {
        super();
        this.window = window;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.colorBG = window.getBackground();
        this.opacity = window.getOpacity();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(final WindowEvent e) {
        colorBG = dialog.getBackground();
        opacity = dialog.getOpacity();
        dialog.setOpacity(1.0f);  // Must call 1st
        dialog.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // Must call 2nd
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(final WindowEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setBackground(colorBG);
                dialog.setOpacity(opacity);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                dialog.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void bugFix_transparentJDialog(final Window parentWindow, JDialog childWindow) {
    if (parentWindow != null && childWindow != null && childWindow.isUndecorated()) {
        final WindowListener[] listeners = parentWindow.getWindowListeners();
        for (int x = 0; x != listeners.length; x++) {
            if (listeners[x] instanceof J42WindowAdapter) {
                final J42WindowAdapter adapter = (J42WindowAdapter) listeners[x];
                if (adapter.window == parentWindow && adapter.dialog == childWindow) {
                    childWindow = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (childWindow != null) {
            parentWindow.addWindowListener(new J42WindowAdapter(parentWindow, childWindow));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Usage example:

```
Helper_Swing.getInstance().bugFix_transparentJDialog(parentWindow, dialog);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bit of a bug to me.

The following seems to work using JDK7 on Windows 7:

```
f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
    {
        d.setVisible(false);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 This solution partially works in the full app.  There are still problems after deiconify with transparency / opacity.  Need to debug further to update the testcase.

Comment: @dubermen, if you are using other transparent components on the dialog then check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.